# Getting error - Unknown Command , while deleting view if exists in oracle

Tags: oracle

```
IF EXISTS(select 1 from sys.views where name='release_testcase_count')
DROP VIEW ITCC.release_testcase_count4;
```

i am able to delete this view but it is saying -

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
IF EXISTS(select 1 from sys.views where name='release_testcase_count')
Error report -
Unknown Command
View ITCC.RELEASE_TESTCASE_COUNT4 dropped.
```

so in this case 1 line have a error, it is not checking it exist or not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen, please look into it

Comment: Where have you seen `IF EXISTS` in the Oracle manual? Other DBs allow that, Oracle does not. Your client (looks like SQL Developer) is saying that's an unknown command, which is right, so it moves onto the next line - which is a complete valid `drop` statement.

Answer (score 0):

IF EXISTS command is valid in SQL Server or other databases but not in ORACLE. 
Your first line is completely ignored and signaled as unknown command as Oracle does not recognize any command starting with `IF EXIST`.

Second line is a valid command, so the view is dropped as a result.